# Cannot lookup row in database by UUID RAW(32)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:

```
create table Mike_Test
( Id          raw(32)      default sys_guid() not null primary key,
  Value        varchar2(80) not null unique
);
```

I now insert into this table:

```
INSERT INTO Mike_Test (VALUE) VALUES ('Blah');
```

I can confirm there's a new row in there:

```
select * from Mike_Test;
```

And I see:

```
08364fc81419429d83c9bcedb24a9a57    Blah
```

Now I try to SELECT that row with:

```
select * from Mike_Test WHERE ID='08364fc81419429d83c9bcedb24a9a57';
```

However, I get zero rows and zero errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yup, read my response below.  Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a RAW datatype, you have to query like this:

```
select .... where id=hextoraw('08364fc81419429d83c9bcedb24a9a57') ....
```

Comment: Yea, I did discover that but was still a bit confused since you'd think I'd get an error if string was indeed "incompatible" with RAW(16).  It turns out that UUID parsing is case sensitive in Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might need to use the [`HEXTORAW`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions071.htm) function around your `ID` value.  This function converts a hex string into the corresponding `RAW` value.

In other words, your query should look like the following:

```
select * from Mike_Test WHERE ID=HEXTORAW('08364fc81419429d83c9bcedb24a9a57');
```

Answer (score 3):

Heh, I did some more toying and the answer is pretty silly.  It seems Oracle will implicitly cast a string to a GUID (like a normal human being would expect), but the casts are case-sensitive!  Which makes absolutely zero sense if you're parsing hexidecimal numbers and casing isn't relative to your base.  The reason this was throwing me off was because I was using Aqua Data Studio, which for some reason displays GUIDs in all lower case.

The following is from SQLPlus, which handles the output correctly:

```
SQL> select * from Mike_Test;

ID
--------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4FBD50C370BC4A7F85E3DF034D120930
Blah


SQL> select * from Mike_Test WHERE ID='4fbd50c370bc4a7f85e3df034d120930';

no rows selected

SQL> select * from Mike_Test WHERE ID='4FBD50C370BC4A7F85E3DF034D120930';

ID
--------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4FBD50C370BC4A7F85E3DF034D120930
Blah
```

Oracle gets sillier each day I use it, I swear.

Comment: Actually, you have this backwards: Oracle implicitly casts the [raw value to a string](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm) for the comparison, which is case-sensitive. See the section in the linked reference titled "Datatype Precedence" for the conversion precedence.

Comment: Really?  That doesn't seem right.  Wouldn't you then have to do a sequential scan on the whole table, converting every row to a string?  Otherwise, you'd have to store the index in its string form which I doubt they would do.

Comment: If indeed what you're saying is correct (I'm in no way doubting you, don't get me wrong), then using the HEXTORAW method from above should hit an index and the string implicit conversion should not..

Comment: This is a well known fact of working with indexed raw columns in Oracle. You have to consider that using a literal is only one type of situation where implicit conversion comes into play. It does, on the face of it, make sense to always convert a literal to match the column type, but then what do you to when you're joining two columns of different types? Oracle made the decision that implicit conversions will always follow the same precedence, placing an value on consistency over the "obvious" approach.

Comment: So, when looking up a row by a RAW(32) column with an index, I should always make sure to cast the value on the right to a RAW(32) as well, otherwise I won't be hitting the index - Is that correct?

Comment: Incidentally, you can see the same effect in the following query: `select * from dba_objects where object_name = 1`. That query will result in an error because Oracle converts the column to a number (resulting in a type conversion error), rather than converting the literal to a string.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  In general, it's always  better to use explicit type conversion, but that's especially true with raw columns.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to my answer (I didn't want to EDIT my original answer since this is such a tangent):

There's huge performance differences between the implicit cast I was trying to do, and the recommended HEXTORAW approach.  The query plan for the implicit cast looks something like:

```
SELECT STATEMENT    3.0 3   37877   1   52  3                   ALL_ROWS                                            
TABLE ACCESS (FULL) 3.0 3   37877   1   52  1   TPMDBO  MIKE_TEST   FULL    TABLE       1
```

And HEXTORAW is:

```
SELECT STATEMENT    1.0 1   15463   1   52  1                   ALL_ROWS                                            
TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID)   1.0 1   15463   1   52  1   TPMDBO  MIKE_TEST   BY INDEX ROWID  TABLE       1                                       
INDEX (UNIQUE SCAN) 1.0 1   8171    1       1   TPMDBO  SYS_C007969 UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE)                  1
```

As you can see, the HEXTORAW approach will hit the primary key index on the table.  This is because the implicit conversion will honor the "string" type of the right operand (the GUID I specify), and convert all the GUIDs in the database to strings.  Definitely something to consider.

Comment: This behaviour is not unique to UUIDs. Implicit data conversion is very often the reason why an index will not be used.